# how to rename the new folder name

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, home-screen-folders, 2.3.3-gingerbread

Hi Guys i need to know how to change the folder name in samsung galaxy ace duos.
I will create it by Tapping up the settings key in the screen and then click on add then Folders but

i couldn't able to rename it. how to rename the folder by default it is coming as folder

Comment: Why downvote for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try tapping on the name of the folder when the folder is open (in this case "Folder"). You may have to do a long-press .

Comment: its not working i already tried its opening the folder instead of name. if long press folder starts moving

Comment: Try it with the folder open

Comment: Now am able to rename